# Can,t resize QWidget from QThread in pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I wanna resize my QWidget from another thread made with QThread but when i do this my application stuck in loading (crashed)

this is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from sys import exit

Application = QApplication([])
Window = QWidget()
thread = QThread()
thread.run = lambda: Window.resize(400, 100)
Window.show()
thread.start()
exit(Application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

No access to QWidgets is allowed from threads other than the *main Qt thread*.
Note that *access* means: creating new widgets, reading/writing widget properties or calls to any of the widget functions.

The only and correct way to do so is to use signals. This allows Qt to *queue* the signal (in case it detects that the sender or the receiver are on different threads) and rely to the receiver as soon as its event queue has been correctly processed.

In order to do so, it's usually better to subclass QThread (it could be theoretically possible to do so without subclassing, but there's no actual benefit and it might just make things more complicated than required).

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from sys import exit
from time import sleep

class Mover(QThread):
    move = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    def run(self):
        sleep(5)
        self.move.emit(400, 100)

Application = QApplication([])
Window = QWidget()
thread = Mover()
thread.move.connect(Window.move)
Window.show()
thread.start()
exit(Application.exec_())
```